# When I follow a link in org-mode the attach directory is not found initially; I always have to execute org-attach-sync first. How can I solve this?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Consider the org-mode section:

- Section
  :PROPERTIES:
  :DIR: directory
  :END

[[attachment:file]]

When I follow this last link for the first time (i.e, I try to open "directory/file"), I get a Yes/No dialog stating "No match - Create this as a new heading?". Then I always have to answer "No" and then execute org-attach-sync for activating the link. How can I solve this problem?, i.e, how can I get org-mode to automatically sync the attach directory and follow the link from the start?

Comment: `org-attach` is not loaded once you load `org`. If you don't mind the startup time, you can just `(with-eval-after-load 'org (require 'org-attach))`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried it and it works.

Comment: As it works, I make my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`org-attach` is not loaded once you load `org`.

If you don't mind the startup time, you can just

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org 
  (require 'org-attach))
```

Or If you want to defer `org-attach`, here is an `use-package` example:

```lisp
  (use-package org-attach
    :defer t
    :commands (org-attach-follow org-attach-complete-link)
    :init
    (org-link-set-parameters "attachment"
                             :follow #'org-attach-follow
                             :complete #'org-attach-complete-link))
```